# how to use pandas.Series.at with pandas.MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, series, multi-index

What is the right way to use `pandas.Series.at` with `pandas.MultiIndex` or it is not supported?

```py
import pandas as pd # pd.__version__ == '0.25.1'

d1 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30], index=[0,1,2])
print(d1.at[1]) # works

d2 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0], [0,1,2]]))
print(d2.at[(0,1)])
# ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers

d3 = pd.Series([10, 20, 30],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[pd.Timestamp('2020-02-24')], [0,1,2]]))
print(d3.at[('2020-02-24',1)])
print(d3.at[(pd.Timestamp('2020-02-24'),1)])
# TypeError: _get_value() got multiple values for argument 'takeable'
```

Here are print-outs of the Series above:

```
>>> print(d1)
0    10
1    20
2    30
dtype: int64
>>> print(d2)
0  0    10
   1    20
   2    30
dtype: int64
>>> print(d3)
2020-02-24  0    10
            1    20
            2    30
dtype: int64
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `loc` with `IndexSlice`

```
print(d2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0,1]])
20
```

Comment: I understand that I can use `loc` instead of `at`: both `d2.loc[(0,1)]` and `d3.loc[('2020-02-24',1)]` work fine. My question is why the same call does not work with `at` and how to fix it.

Comment: @S.V this is how at and iat works~ https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9259

Comment: Thank you for the link! I do not understand the logic though: why `at` with a `DataFrame` is fine but it is not fine with a `Series`: both `d2.to_frame().at[(0,1), 0]` and `d3.to_frame().at[('2020-02-24',1), 0]` work fast and without any error messages.